# Using OpenJDK 9 EA with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classnotfoundexception, java-9

Right now I'm trying to setup IntelliJ to play around with OpenJDK 9 which I downloaded and installed from [here](http://openjdk.java.net/). I got the 64 bit Windows version. I added JDK 9 by going to Project Structure and adding the directory **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9** as a new SDK. Everything looks great and normal until I try to actually run the program, then this happens.

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError) Could not initialize class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory$PlatformMBeanFinder
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory$PlatformMBeanFinder
    at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBeans(ManagementFactory.java:684)
    at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans(ManagementFactory.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.LowMemoryWatcher.<clinit>(LowMemoryWatcher.java:84)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:118)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:126)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.createMap(AbstractStateStorage.java:136)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.<init>(AbstractStateStorage.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.TimestampStorage.<init>(TimestampStorage.java:36)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.ProjectTimestamps.<init>(ProjectTimestamps.java:36)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:90)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:266)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:232)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1158)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:632)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:804)
```

Has anyone else ran across this issue and found a way to use JDK 9 with IntelliJ?

Comment: Guess not, eh? Any update?

Comment: I never could resolve the issue. I assume that by the time JDK 9 is officially released jetbrains will have released a version of IntelliJ that works easily with it. I'm in the .Net world now so I probably won't be trying to figure this out again any time soon.

Answer (score 2):

**Maybe** you have to try an older version of jdk. I have the same problem with you and I select an older version of jdk in IntelliJ. 
But I still have problem installing Eclipse with java 9-ea. this is my post:[With java 9 ea, Eclipse fails to install and show error "An error has occurred, see the log file null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43165556/with-java-9-ea-eclipse-fails-to-install-and-show-error-an-error-has-occurred)