# With java 9 ea, Eclipse fails to install and show error "An error has occurred, see the log file null"

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, java-9

I know this problem occurs many time, but I have find a similar situation like I have.

Every time I click the Eclipse Installer, I will get a prompt:An error has occurred, see the log file null. I can't even install Eclipse.

I guess the problem is due to "JDK 9-ea", so I am planing to uninstall jdk 9-ea and use jdk8, but maybe you can help me to solve this problem directly, thanks !

Comment: It is much too early to use JDK 9 as the JRE for "regular programs" - you should use Java 8 for that.

Comment: I uninstall java 9 as well as jdk 9-ea, and install java 1.8.0_111, now I can install Eclipse on my mac, problem solved, thanks :)

Comment: @AndyLiu I'm on a Mac running jdk-9 in Eclipse for about 3 months now without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to get the correct install most probably, here is the `Oxygen 4.7 M6` link : http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.7M6-201703082000/

Or the direct [link](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.7M6-201703082000/download.php?dropFile=eclipse-SDK-4.7M6-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz) to the `.tar.gz`

Then (after you untar the archive), go to :

```
Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini
```

and add one parameter **after -vmargs**. It should look like this:

```
-vmargs
--add-modules=java.se.ee
```

This will allow you to start the Eclipse under jdk-9.

In case you want to install the jdk-9 plugin (so that you could compile code under jdk-9):  you need to install the Experimental Plugin for jdk-9. There were some problems with that (I filed a bug that was closed), see [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509354) thread. At the end there is the link for on how to get the plugin.

Then you need to follow the **exact** instructions [here](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-9-support-beta-oxygen) for it to actually work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have already uninstalled jdk9 and I find that I have installed 2 different versions of jdks on by mac, maybe that's why I can't run jdk9 properly, thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding this line to the eclipse.ini "--add-modules=java.se.ee" will resolve the whole issue

mine is macOs and Java 9 installed alone without any other version

Hope this helps